# AWS S3 doesObjectExist costs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

AWS S3 Java SDK provides a method `doesObjectExist()` to check if an object exists in S3. What operation does it use internally? Is it `GET`, `LIST`, or `HEAD` ?

My concern is mainly related to its costs. From S3 documentation the costs of US west Oregon are-
PUT, COPY, POST, or LIST Requests   $0.005 per 1,000 requests

GET, SELECT and all other Requests  $0.0004 per 1,000 requests

Does the cost of `doesObjectExist()` fall under 1st or 2nd category? Also I was reading somewhere that this operation requires `ListBucket` and `GetObject` permissions. So does that mean this operation incurs cost of both the above categories?

Comment: AWS SDK for which language?

Comment: @emix Java. I updated the post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the code, the `doesObjectExist()` method internally calls `getObjectMetadata` ([link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2d15a603a96f98076f5458db49d659f296eab313/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1321), [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2d15a603a96f98076f5458db49d659f296eab313/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1243)).

If you go [a little deeper](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2d15a603a96f98076f5458db49d659f296eab313/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1261) into the code, the actual HTTP request is a `HEAD` request, so I strongly suspect they are just doing a `HEAD` on the object itself.

The description of [`GetObjectMetadataRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectMetadataRequest.html) and the [`HEAD` call on the REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html) are also similar.

Regarding permissions, you are correct (the excerpt below also comes from the `HEAD` request on the REST API):

> You need the s3:GetObject permission for this operation.  For more information, go to Specifying Permissions in a Policy in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide. If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the s3:ListBucket permission.

Comment: thanks for pointing out to the code. So under all conditions(whether object exists or not)  it will be costed under 'GET, SELECT, other requests' category?

Comment: Correct. Even though the HEAD request is technically different from a GET (and if you enable S3 bucket logs, you'll see different results for both), the pricing is the same. You'll save money on data transfer using the HEAD, since you obviously don't get the file contents in the payload.