# How to get S3 URL for the object from S3 bucket using aws-sdk-2.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

We were using the AWS Java SDK-1.x version in our application till now. We decided to migrate to the 2.x. As per my analysis I have found out the equivalent function which we are using for 1.x client operation in 2.x in our application. But for some operation I could not able to find matching functions. Below are the details.

| 1.x (AmazonS3) | 2.x (S3AsyncClient) |
| --- | --- |
| getObject(String bucket, String key) | getObject(GetObjectRequest req, Path destination) |
| putObject(String bucket, String key, File file) | putObject(PutObjectRequest req, Path source) |
| generatePresignedUrl(GeneratePresignedUrlRequest req) | S3PreSigner.presignGetObject(GetObjectPresignRequest req) |
| deleteObject(String bucket, String key) | deleteObject(DeleteObjectRequest req) |
| getUrl(String bucket, String key) | ? |
| doesObjectExist(String bucket, String key) | ? |

Any help or pointer is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the replacements for the methods that you are looking for in 2.x SDK:

| 1.11.x Operation | 2.0 Operation |
| --- | --- |
| `getUrl` | [S3Utilities#getUrl](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/7428f629753c603f96dd700ca686a7b169fc4cd4/services/s3/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Utilities.java#L140) |
| `doesObjectExist` | `headObject` |

Here is a complete mapping of [S3 1.x and 2.0 Operations](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/docs/LaunchChangelog.md#411-s3-operation-migration).

Comment: Just to update the `headObject` method call throws `NoSuchKeyException` when key is not present in in S3 bucket. I can handle that exception though, but if there is a method which can return `boolean` if the object is present in S3 or not that would be better.

Comment: I think this is what `doesObjectExist` method was doing earlier, now you have to do it manually. Refer this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820694/1273882

Comment: Thank you for reference and above answer.